# Retropie UI mode error: Kids ui has nothing to show

Tags: raspbian, retropie

I recently installed raspbian and after that I installed retropie on my pi 3 B+. I installed emulationstation-dev from experimental to get the KID ui mode
like this:
[image]

The KIOSK UI mode works fine but with the KID mode I get This error:

```
The selected UI mode has nothing to show, returning to UI mode: FULL
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's displaying this message because you have no games tagged as kid games.

To tag a game as a kidgame, in Full mode, scroll until the game you want to tag, press <kbd>Select</kbd>, then select `Edit This Game's Metadata`.

Scroll until `Kidgame` and toggle to `On`.

Now you have at least one game tagged as Kidgame, and then Kid mode will work.